# Directadmin httpd dead but pid file exists

Tags: apache-2.2

I checked Service Monitor and saw

> httpd Process is stopped

Then I try to use root for restart httpd. It still the same
Then I check httpd status
It's shown

> httpd dead but pid file exists

Im using DirectAdmin 1.50.0, Apache 2.2.31

I have try to kill process and restart it again but It doesnt work. any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You need to check the logs and find out why httpd doesn't start properly.

Comment: Also.. **Questions involving web hosting control panels** are off-topic at [sf] because they [customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8055), and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your old pidfile

```
sudo rm /var/run/httpd.pid
```

And try again